# Can we use the JVM as an app container?

Tags: java, architecture, jvm, lxc, linux-containers

Can the JVM be flexible/parameterizable enough to be used as we use linux containers? (cgroups, fs and memory restricted, etc.)

What you guys think about it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that as there is Docker already?

Comment: It's more about to try simplify the layers: if we can use the JVM, why to use docker?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. The JVM doesn't most of what people need in Java.  There are plenty of Web Server and OSGi containers which are used every day just fine.

Comment: The JVM and Docker serve different purposes; having one monolithic layer that serves all purposes *complicates* things, rather than simplifies them.